# CodeIgniter - Could still access the member's page after logging out when back button is clicked

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using **CodeIgniter**.

After I logon to the member's and click logout, I could still view the member's page when
I click the BACK button.

**Question**
Does anyone know so that if the user has logged out, it could not access the Member's page even clicking of BACK button?

Please see my code below..

Thanks..

```
    class Site extends CI_Controller{

    function index()
    {   
        if(!isset($this->session->userdata['is_loggged_in'])) 
            $this->login(); 
        else 
            $this->_template();      
    }

    function login()
    { 
        $data['main_content'] = 'login_form';
        $data['page_title']   = 'Login - php';
        $this->load->view('include/template' , $data);  
    }

    function validate()
    {  
        $this->load->library('form_validation'); 
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username' , 'Username' , 'trim|required' );
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password' , 'Password' , 'trim|required' ); 

        if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $this->login();
        } 
        else
        { 
            $this->load->model('member_model' , 'member');
            $query = $this->member->checklogin(); 

            //login successful , make sure no duplicate entry during registration
            if($query->num_rows() == 1)
            {
                $data = array(
                    'is_loggged_in' => TRUE ,
                    'username'      => $this->input->post('username'), 
                );
                $this->session->set_userdata($data);
                $this->_template();
            }
            else
            { 
                $data = array(
                        'main_content' => 'login_form' ,
                        'page_title'   => 'Error login' ,
                        'page_error'   => 'Invalid Username or password. '

                );
                $this->load->view('include/template' , $data); 
            }

        }
    }

    function _template()
    { 
        $data = array(
            'main_content' => 'include/default_inc',
            'page_title'   => 'Welcome home ran'
        ); 

        $this->load->view('include/template' , $data);  
    }

    function logout()
    { 
        $this->session->sess_destroy();
        redirect('site/login');
        exit;
    }
  }

/* end of controller site */
```

Comment: Check wether your session is getting destroyed after clicking logout.Also add a checking in every pages wther session is set else redirect to login

Comment: Verify the status of the $_SESSION to confirm that it is being destroyed. You could use a print_r($_SESSION).

Comment: Portu, CI doesn't use the $_SESSION variable.

Comment: @Fibbe Thanks for the heads up, I have not had the opportunity to work with CI, so I do appreciate your input. I thought it would be just matter of checking the status of the session but it looks like there is more than a $_SESSION variable behind the scenes.

Comment: Clicking `back` button doesn't reload the page. However you logged out, you still access the previous page. But, if you refresh/reload the page you will be brought to login page

Comment: Actually, I have the same case, and I have to solve it

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your session is succesfully getting destroyed but still the previous page is getting accessed(from browser's history), then you can solve this by using code in your every `controllers constructor`. I would suggest to extend core `Output` Library.

```
    $this->output->set_header('Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
    $this->output->set_header('Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, max-age=0');
    $this->output->set_header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0', FALSE);
    $this->output->set_header('Pragma: no-cache');
```

Answer (score 2):

this is the logic

if you disable cache in all controller, it will works but it is stupid. maybe it will slowdown your web loads, or even affect your SEO.

So the solution is always check user status in every pages, if his status is logged in then disable cache, otherwise do nothing

this is a sample part of my code that i put in every function

```
if ($this->session->userdata('logged_in')){
     $this->output->set_header('Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
     $this->output->set_header('Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, max-age=0');
     $this->output->set_header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0', FALSE);
     $this->output->set_header('Pragma: no-cache');}
```

no need to put else statement after that, just put the rest of your code .

So one the user logged id and browsing your web, there is no cache being stored. Try to log out and hit back button. i bet it works

Answer (score 1):

instead of checking session in  index function try checking it in constructor

```
function __constuctor()
{   
    parent::__construct();
    $session = $this->session->userdata('is_loggged_in');
    if ( !$session) {
        $this->login(); 
    }else{
        $this->_template();    
    }     
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Basicly your browser goes back a page and simply reproduces the HTML it received that time. There are many ways to solve this, and I promise you can easily find them through little searching.

One simply way to prevent this would be to run an ajax upon page load that checks if you're logged in, and updates the page if that's not the case. And ajax will always be run, even through using Back.

**controllers/check_login.php**

```
<?

class Check_login {

    function index()
    {
        $bool = (bool) $this->session->userdata('is_loggged_in');

        $this->output->set_content_type('application/json');
        if ($bool)
            $this->output->set_status_header('500');

        $arr_json = array( 'need_login' => $bool);

        echo json_encode($arr_json);
    }

}
```

**jQuery javascript**

```
$(function() {

    $(document).ajaxError(function(event, jqXHR) {

        var data    =   jqXHR.responseJSON;

        if (data.need_login)
            if (confirm(data.message))
                window.location = window.location.href;

       $.get('/check_login');

    });

});
```

**Note!** This approach can also give you a easy way to handle dead ajax calls through clever use of `$this->input->is_ajax_request()` and `'need_login'` value.

Comment: That is the way I did with some changes. It works well to solve the problem above. vote it up

Answer (score 1):

From your code , you are logged out, even the html page is cached by the browser therefore such problem occurs. I am providing a well tested solution.
.Put following code somewhere in your helper (lets say my_helper.php).

```
function no_cache()
{
    header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1990 05:00:00 GMT");
    header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
    header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
    header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
}
```

Load the helper and call the no_cache function within the constructor of your controller

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper('my_helper');
    no_cache();

}
```